# Deactivate tooltip on a given page

Tags: html, tooltip

What is the "correct" way to deactivate tooltips on a given page so that the title attribute of a tag does not get shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific "correct" way.

If you don't want a title on an element, don't put one there.

If they must exist, you can use JavaScript to remove the title from any element you need to.

The issue here is that how the attribute is displayed is browser dependent - [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3) says so:

> Values of the title attribute may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways. For instance, visual browsers frequently display the title as a "tool tip" (a short message that appears when the pointing device pauses over an object).

The fact that they display as a tooltip in most visual browsers does not mean they *have* to be. And there is no specific standard mechanism to "disable" this behavior.

Comment: the browser dependency is a main issue here

Comment: @Thariama - exactly. This is _browser_ defined, so there is no general way to control this, apart from removing the attribute altogether.

Comment: well, i was interessted in the existance of a 'correct way' without removing the title attribute

Comment: @Thariama - Well, that's the point. There is no such "correct way". Unless you can convince all browser vendors to standardize on a client side method to suppress these tooltips.

Comment: that's what i thought, answer acepted